# getting clusters from R's heatmap function?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, heatmap, hierarchical-clustering

I am using R's `heatmap` function to do hierarchical clustering (http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/stats/heatmap). Is there a function that takes the object returned by `heatmap` and gives back the clustering you get by applying a threshold `alpha` to the dendrogram? A function like:

```
h <- heatmap(...)
clusters <- get_clusters(h, alpha=0.5)
```

where `clusters` is an array of same length as number of columns of the input dataframe, and returns a number between 0 and n-1 for each entry, where n is number of columns (assignment of columns to clusters). Does this exist in R?

Comment: if you haven't changed the default distance or clustering function calls to `heatmap()` then you can just call `hclust(dist(x))` where `x` is the first parameter you've given to the `heatmap()` function.

Comment: I think you may find `cutree` function quite helpful. See the examples at the bottom of its [documentation page](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/cutree.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the `keep.dendro` argument of the `heatmap` function. The dendrograms are then stored in the `Rowv` and `Colv` elements of the output.

```
x = matrix(rnorm(25), ncol=5)
h = heatmap(x, keep.dendro=TRUE)
```

Next, convert the `dendrogram` object to a `hclust` object with the `as.hclust` function. Then, as stated in the comments, you can use `cutree` to get clusters.

```
row.clusters = as.hclust(h$Rowv)
cutree(row.clusters, k=3)  # break into k=3 clusters
```

Of course, you could have gotten to `row.clusters` by just doing

```
row.clusters = hclust(dist(x))
```